# With ffmpeg's example extract_mvs.c, I am getting black and white images from color rtsp camera

Tags: libavcodec

I am using the extract_mvs.c from ffmpeg:

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/extract__mvs_8c_source.html

I added opencv to imwrite the image.

```
cv::Mat img(frame->height,frame->width,CV_8UC1,frame->data[0]); 
imwrite( "pic.jpg", img );
```

That works because the image in the frame is in grayscale.  The camera is a color camera however, and I dont know why I am getting grayscale.  If I cange the above to CV_8UC3, I get segmentation fault.

I tried to save the image with  ppm_save function and I still get a black and white frame when there should be a color frame.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just read about graphics file formats and such.  JPG requires BGR24 format. The raw frame buffer format YUV420P needs to be converted to BGR24 using swscale.  Then the output frames height and width needs to be manually set before calling :

```
cv::Mat img(out_frame->height,out_frame->width,CV_8UC3,out_frame->data[0]); 
imwrite( "pic.jpg", img );
```

Likewise,PPM file format requires RGB24 and the raw format needs to be converted to this before saving the ppm file.

Thanks,
Chris